# Frequency distributions in R

Tags: r, distribution, frequency

I'm currently working with a fairly large dataset and am wondering how I would go about getting frequency distributions of raw scores in R (raw scores are currently dichotomized, but not sure if a frequency distribution would be easier to execute using non-dichotomous raw scores). The variables are questions 1-50 and the rows are the IDs.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Darko

Comment: You're not really giving us much to work on here. What does the data look like? Have you tried tabulating it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `freq()` function of the `AMR` package.

```
install.packages("AMR")
library(AMR)

freq(mtcars$mpg)
```

It also support quasi quotation:

```
# use the tidyverse piping
mtcars %>% freq(mpg)
```